# How can two different utility functions represent the same preferences?

Tags: utility, preferences

I have this question for microecon that asks do the following utility functions represent the same preferences:

1. $u(x_1, x_2) = x1 \cdot x2, \; v(x_1, x_2) = \ln x_1 + \ln x_2$
2. $u(x_1, x_2) = x1 \cdot x2, \; v(x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2$

How do I go about approaching this problem since they are two different functions?

Comment: Did you learn that [utility is ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_utility)?

Comment: yes, I know that the ordering of the numbers matter which is why there are many utility functions that represent the same preferences. I'm just getting stuck on this specific one

Comment: Read the article linked in my previous comment. The second sentence therein answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, an utility function $u: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ represents the preference relation $\succsim$ if: $$\forall a, b \in X, \; u(a) \geq u(b) \iff a \succsim b.$$

Well, if another function $v: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ represents $\succsim$, then: $$\forall a, b \in X, \; v(a) \geq v(b) \iff a \succsim b.$$

But the above implies the following:

$$\forall a, b \in X, \; u(a) \geq u(b) \iff v(a) \geq v(b).$$

Which means that both functions preserves the order relation, just as Herr K. said it. Another important part of Wikipedia's article is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_utility#Uniqueness). You see, any monotonically increasing (and it must be increasing, not nondecreasing) function preserves the preference relation.

So now I think you will be able to answer both questions. As a tip for the first one, think about the $\ln(x)$ function: is it a monotonic increasing function?